# OpenGL not working on an old laptop

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, opengl

So yesterday I decided to do a minimal install on my T30 (the Thinkpad, not the tank) that has Mobility Radeon 7500 graphics and everything was pretty smooth besides the fact that any packages that needed OpenGL like qutebrowser and cool-retro-term threw errors. I figured it wasn't the packages at fault but rather my last century graphics adapter.

I did some research and found someone saying on the [ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1015477) that there aren't any drivers available besides the default open source ones. Before throwing in the towel I was just wondering, is there anything I can do to be able to run packages that need OpenGL?

Comment: Sorry, can't find an OpenGL driver for the Radeon 7500.

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't find anything either, but thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Also https://forum.thinkpads.com/search.php?keywords=Linux+OpenGL&fid%5B0%5D=28 had nada.

Comment: Yeah seems that many people say that its no longer supported, that is probably the case. Well, if anything its still usable as is, but thank you for helping!